# How to change the qTip2 arrow color?

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, qtip2

I use qTip2 (see http://qtip2.com/) to show detailed information of an event within a tooltip. I browsed the qTip Documentation to find a way to change the color of the arrow. Sadly i was only able to change the size of the arrow, but not the color itself. Any idea?

[Here is a screenshot of the current state. The black arrow should be coloured white.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlMJP.png)

Thats my current implementation:

```
element.qtip({
            content: event.renderedEventTooltip,
            hide: {
                delay: 200,
                fixed: true,
            },
            style: {
                tip: {
                    width: 30,
                    height: 15,
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top center',
                at: 'bottom center',
                viewport: jQuery('#calendar'),
                adjust: {
                    method: 'shift',
                    resize: false,
                }
            },
        });
```

Comment: Yes, great thing. But what should be coloured? The background is the wrong property, the color too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to color of the tip per CSS and the attribute border-color. For example:

```
.qtip-tip { border-color: white; }
```

Comment: I made a quick codepen for this, seems to work if you set `border: 0;` to `.qtip`:

https://codepen.io/therobotzombie/pen/mdPXRdR